# Why is the weak* topology not in general metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-groups

A Banach space is a topological group under addition. The dual is a topological group under the weak$^*$ topology. The weak$^*$ topology is weaker than the operator norm topology, so is it first-countable? It is also Hausdorff. (Seems intuitively obvious, might require the Hahn-Banach Theorem to make rigorous). So by the Birkhoff-Kakutani Theorem it should be metrizable. But I believe this is only the case for the finite-dimensional case. Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: "The weak* topology is weaker than the operator norm topology, so is first-countable" is, except in the finite-dimensional case, wrong.

Comment: First countability doesn't transfer to stronger or weaker topologies. Discrete topology and trivial topology are both always first countable and any topology is between the two.

Answer (score 4):

If a topological space is metrizable, then it has to be first countable.

It turns out that, if $X$ has uncountable base (as a linear space), then the weak$^*$ topology of $X^*$ is not first countable. See

[The weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ is not first countable if $X$ has uncountable dimension.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623642/the-weak-topology-on-x-is-not-first-countable-if-x-has-uncountable-dimen/626599#626599)

But, even if the dimension of a normed space is $\aleph_0$, then its dual shall coincide with the dual of the completion of $X$, which will have dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$, and hence the weak$^*$ topology of $X^*$ will not be first countable, as well.

Comment: Is the weak* topology on $X^*$ induced by the completion of $X$ the same as the weak* topology on $X^*$ induced by $X$?

Comment: If and only if $X$ is complete. I'm sure that was a rhetorical question by @DavidMitra, but just in case somebody doesn't know: if $Y$ is a (linear) subspace of the completion of $X$ such that $\lambda\lvert_Y = \mu\lvert_Y \implies \lambda = \mu$ for $\lambda,\mu\in X^\ast$, then the dual space of $X^\ast$ with the weak* topology induced by $Y$ is $Y$, so no two such subspaces induce the same weak* topology on $X^\ast$.

Comment: Please explain more about when "the dimension of a normed space is ℵ 0 " part. Reading above result, I can not understand it or give me a reference about it.

Comment: Dear @DanielFischer or others also who could give me a hand : what happens if $X$ is not Banach? I am not sure why this is neccessary (or convenient) in the above argument. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if $X$ is not Banach? Can't we say also that then its dual has an uncountble dimension? @DavidMitra Thank you.

Comment: Dear @Yiorgos, could you please give a reference of where can I read that the dimension of continuous dual is also always strictly bigger than that of the original space? And what happens if $X$ is not Banach?