# give necessary and sufficient conditions that every functional in $w^*-cl M$ be the $w^*$- limit of a sequence from M

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. If $M$ is a linear manifold in $X^*$ give necessary and sufficient conditions that every functional in $w^*-\mathrm{cl} M$ be the $w^*$- limit of a sequence from M.

My attempt: I suppose $A$ is a w* - closed set and $M=\text{linear span}~ A$. Suppose $\phi \in w^*- \mathrm{cl}  M$. Because $w^*- cl M = ||.||-\mathrm{cl}  M$, we have $\phi \in ||.||- cl M$ . Thus there is a sequence $\{\phi_n\}$ in $M$ such that $\phi=||.||-\lim \phi_n$, and  clearly $\phi=w^*-\lim \phi_n$.

Conversely, suppose $\phi=w^*-\lim \phi_n$ where $\{\phi_n\}$ is a sequence in $M$. Clearly $N(\phi,x_1,...,x_n,\epsilon)\cap M\not=\varnothing$, for every $\epsilon>0$ , $x_i\in X$.

I do not know my proof is correct or not. Also I do not use the condition  $M=\text{linear span}~ A$ for the second part. Please help me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a theorem: If A is weak* closed subset of $X^*$ and $M=\text{linear span} A$, then M is weak* closed iff it is norm closed. To use this theorem I introduced A.

Comment: sorry, There is a mistake in type. A is weak* closed. I correct it

Comment: The question asked me to put conditions on it. so in this case I think it's correct. Is not it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood that you were stating assumptions.  I would recommend that you organize your writing to make it clearer what you are attempting to show, but apologies for my misinterpretation. (I'll delete my obsolete comment.)

Comment: It is not true in general, I don't think, that the norm-closure coincides with the weak*-closure.  If the set is convex, then it coincides with the weak-closure, but this is not good enough for your purpose.  Your converse does not prove what you need to prove, either.  You need to conclude that $M$ is the linear span of some weak*-closed set, which you do not do.  Probably, your condition is equivalent to M itself being weak*-closed.

Comment: I think $M$ is first countable w.r.t. to weak* topology. Now ue ideas of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623642/the-weak-topology-on-x-is-not-first-countable-if-x-has-uncountable-dim)

Comment: hatsoff@ I put the condition "A is weak* closed subset of X∗ and M=linear span A" on the question and want to show every functional in w∗−clM be the w∗- limit of a sequence from M. So I think it's not necessary to show M is the linear span of some weak*-closed set. Also I put this condition to use theorem 6.12.9 of conway's functional analysis "If A is weak* closed subset of X∗ and M=linear spanA, then M is weak* closed iff it is norm closed." For converse I show if $\phi=w^*-\lim \phi_n$ then $\phi\in w^*- cl M$.