# Show that $T^*$ is weak$^*$-to-weak$^*$ continuous

Tags: continuity, banach-spaces, compactness, weak-convergence

> Suppose $Y$ is a separable Banach space and $(y^*_n)_{n \in
> > \mathbb{N}} \subset B_{Y^*}$. Let $T : X \rightarrow Y$ be an
>   operator. Since $Y$ is separable, we have the unit dual ball $B_{Y^*}$
>   is metrisable in its weak$^*$ topology, hence there exists a
>   weak$^*$-convergent subsequence $(y^*_{n_j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ of
>   $(y^*_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then, $(T^*(y^*_{n_j}))_{j \in
> > \mathbb{N}}$ is also weak$^*$-convergent as $T^*$ is w$^*$-to-w$^*$
>   convergent.

The statement above is the proof of [Proposition $6.2$](http://www.impan.pl/~tkoch/teaching/cbst_lecture_6.pdf).

Questions:

$(1)$ Why there exists weak$^*$-convergent subsequence $(y^*_{n_j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$?

$(2)$ Why $T^* : Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ is weak$^*$-to-weak$^*$ continuous if $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous?

My thought:

$(1)$ Since $B_{Y^*}$ is metrisable in its weak$^*$ topology, we have $B_{Y^*}$ is finite-dimensional. Hence, $B_{Y^*}$ is compact. In metric space, compact is equivalent with sequential compact, hence the existence of the subsequence.

$(2)$ Suppose $T$ is continuous. Let $(y^*_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be a sequence in $Y^*$ which converges to $y^*$ in $w^*$ topology. Then for any $y \in Y$, we have 
$$|y_n^*(y) - y^*(y)| < \epsilon.$$

In particular, for any $Tx \in Y$, we have 
$$|y_n^*(Tx) - y^*(Tx)| < \epsilon.$$

Note that $|(T^*y_n^*)(x) - (T^*y^*)(x)| = |y_n^*(Tx) - y^*(Tx)|<\epsilon.$

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separability of $Y$ implies that the weak star topology on the dual unit ball is metrizable, eg, suppose that $x_n$ is a dense set of $B_Y$. Then $d(x^*, y^*) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|(x^* - y^*)(x_n)|}{2^n}$ provides a metric. One can check that this is equivalent. The fact that this is non zero for every $x,y$ follows, eg, as $(x^* - y^*)$ has some element $z$ in the unit ball for which $(x^* - y^*)(z) = \|x^* - y^*\|$, so if $x_M$ is sufficiently close to $z$ the two things differ.

The unit ball of $Y^*$ is compact in the weak star topology (Banach-Alaoglu) and metrizable, so every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

$T$ is continuous from $X$ to $Y$ and so $T^*$ is weak star to weak star continuous from $Y^*$ to $X^*$. This is easy to establish.

Comment: Regarding the continuity implies its adjoint is $w^*$ to $w^*$ continuous, is my proof correct?

Comment: The closed unit ball of $Y^{\ast}$ is metrisable in the weak$^{\ast}$ topology. $Y^{\ast}$ itself is not metrisable in the weak$^{\ast}$ topology generally (if $Y$ is Banach, then if and only if $Y$ is finite-dimensional).

Comment: @DanielFischer: can explain your sentence in bracket? 'if $Y$ is Banach, then if and only if $Y$ is finite dimensional'. Do you mean $Y$ is metrisable if and only if $Y$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: @Idonknow If $Y$ is a Banach space, then $Y^{\ast}$ is metrisable in the weak$^{\ast}$ topology if and only if $Y$ is finite-deminsional.

Comment: @Idonknow: Daniel Fischer [is right](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623642/the-weak-topology-on-x-is-not-first-countable-if-x-has-uncountable-dim), James's claim is false and his answer is not correct.