# Question 3.8 from Brezis' book of Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, baire-category, weak-topology, metrizability

**QUESTION:** Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Our purpose is to show that $E'$ equipped with the weak $^\star$ topology is not metrizable. Suppose, by contradiction, that there is a metric $d(x,y)$ on $E'$ that induces on $E'$ the same topology as $\sigma(E', E)$. Prove that $E'$ equipped with the weak$^\star$ topology $\sigma(E',E)$ is not metrizable.

**HINT IN BREZIS' BOOK:** Apply the following lemma: Assume that $x_1, x_1, \cdots, x_k, y\in E$ satisfy
$$[f\in E';\langle f, x_i \rangle =0\; \forall i]\implies [\langle f, y \rangle=0].$$
Then there exist constants $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots, \lambda_k$ such that $y=\displaystyle\sum^{k}_{i=1}\lambda_ix_i$.

**DOUBT:** Would you give me a hint how to start this problem and where to use this lemma? I tried to do the same for weak topology, but I'm not very confident about what I wrote. So, I would like to be sure at least about this part about weak$^{\star}$ topology, then I can check and do similar proof for the first parte.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The weak$^*$ topology on $X^*$ is not first countable if $X$ has uncountable dimension.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623642/the-weak-topology-on-x-is-not-first-countable-if-x-has-uncountable-dim)

Comment: What is 'first countable'? I checked but I think is not the same, I do not know the meaning of 'first countable'? Is this about topology?

Comment: Yes, first countable = every point has a countable neighborhood basis. That is, for every $x$ there are $\{V_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ nbhds. of $x$ such that for every nbhd. $N$ of $x$ there is $N_0$ such that $V_{N_0} \subset N$. Every metrizable space is first countable (take $B(x,1/n), n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @fbianchini Thank you for the explanation